# PostgreSQL string_to_array double quotes causing problem

Tags: postgresql, double, quote

In the below example tss should be equal to check given the argument of the function is 'WW123 (TestTest 20)®TEST50®®40®France™WW123 (TestTest 20)®TEst50®®40®Fra' but something goes wrong check becomes "WW123 (TestTest 20) (note the double quotes in the beginning).

Anyone having any idea where is the issue? Is it a bug in PostgreSQL 9.6?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.test_function (
  a_test text
)
RETURNS text AS
$body$
DECLARE
v_combinations text[];
v_combination text;
v_combination_elements text [ ]; 
  tss text;
check text;  
BEGIN
v_combinations = string_to_array(a_test,'™');

FOREACH v_combination in array v_combinations
LOOP
v_combination_elements = string_to_array(v_combination,'®');

FOR i in 1..array_length(v_combination_elements,1)-2

loop
  tss = 'WW123 (TestTest 20)';
  check = v_combination_elements[i];
  if tss = v_combination_elements[i]
  then 
  return 'Yes';
  else
  return 'No';
  end if;
 end loop;

END LOOP;

  RETURN TSS;
END;
```

Comment: I tried it and raised notice and didn't see any quotes.

Comment: @eurotrash Certainly there is something strange. See the image: https://imgur.com/a/oPOSvQS

Comment: Try to show the behaivior in dbfiddle or https://rextester.com/: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=830db44e1ce1e62c88f9f7a3e927bbb3